# Why are not the dotted line and the page number showed up while using the acronym package with the xepersian package?

Tags: acronyms, bidi

In the code below, despite using the `withpage` option, the dotted line and the page number are not showed up in the output pdf. How can I fix this problem?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\usepackage{xepersian} % http://ctan.org/pkg/xepersian
\begin{document}
\chapter{تست}
\section{تست}
تست
\ac{GSM} 
\section{نمادها}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{GSM}[$G_sm$]{مجموعه فلان}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Please note that the code should be run using `xelatex`.

Comment: I see something curios in the `.aux` file. It seems an `\undonewlabel` is issued before `\newacro` and thus, there is no acronym to show. If you remove the xepersin, all the farsi texts and compile with pdflatex, the `.aux` file is different in the way that there is a `\newlabel` after `\undonewlabel` and before `\newacro`. If you reorder the xepersian aux file manually, you will have acronyms shown properly. It seems someone is failing to make a newlable. I guess this is the problem but in all honesty, I don't know the workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Why This Happens?

In your `.aux` file, the three related macro should appear in the following order:

```
\undonewlabel
\newlabel
\acronymused
```

when the direction is LTR, the order is right but when it is RTL, the order gets reversed so you will get:

```
\acronymused
\newlabel
\undonewlabel
```

and this is the root of your issue.

## More Primary Analysis

With

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\test{%
\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\large}%
\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\Large}%
\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\Huge}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
This is a test \test
\end{document}
```

One in the `.aux` file, should get:

```
\large
\Large
\Huge
```

However, when you enable `TeX--XeT`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\test{%
\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\large}%
\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\Large}%
\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\Huge}%
}
\makeatother
\TeXXeTstate=1
\begin{document}
This is a test \beginR\test\endR
\end{document}
```

The order will be reversed in the `.aux` file:

```
\Huge
\Large
\large
```

This simply reverses the order. Note that this only happens in horizontal mode. I think this is an `etex` bug or a very bad feature (if not bug).

## What is the Workaround?

This should be fixed inside the engine; at the macro level, one can put them at the reverse order in RTL so when it gets reversed, it will be in the right order. Note that the macro level solution is only temporary and not reliable; here is such workaround:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\usepackage{xepersian} % http://ctan.org/pkg/xepersian
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@verridelabel[1]{%
  \@bsphack
  \label{#1}%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\undonewlabel{#1}}%
  \@overriddenmessage rs{#1}%
  \@esphack
}%
\renewcommand*{\@acf}[1]{%
      \ifAC@starred\else\AC@logged{#1}\fi%
       \acffont{%
          \AC@placelabel{#1}\hskip\z@\AC@acl{#1}%
          \nolinebreak[3] %
          \acfsfont{(\acsfont{\AC@acs{#1}})}%
        }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{تست}
\section{تست}
تست
\ac{GSM} 
\section{نمادها}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{GSM}[$G_sm$]{مجموعه فلان}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems more logical to use only one `\protected@write`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\test{%
\protected@write\@auxout{}{%
\string\large^^J%
\string\Large^^J%
\string\Huge%
}}
\makeatother
\TeXXeTstate=1
\begin{document}
This is a test \beginR\test\endR
\end{document}
```

Then the order would be right.